# What are various sources for icons? (even paid icons will work)

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking icons for my service based firm. Like ruby on rails icons, php, iphone and android.
Some other icons like web development and all.

PS:- Its good be be free, but I dont mind spending some bucks.

I already tried:--

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=icons

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icons?sort=votes&pagesize=50

I am looking for some icons like this:--

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try [IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/). Its free but you can also buy icons so that others can not use that icon.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Iconfactory](http://iconfactory.com/), they have both shareware and freeware sections. If you need something more specific you can always ask for a custom design from their's [StockIcons](http://stockicons.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Also, try [iStockphoto](http://www.istockphoto.com), put "icon" in the search field. You find there as well 3D images,(you can restrict to only have vectorial results, but I'd look in normal raster, as well..) high quality images, etc. They don't let just any thing to be uploaded: there is a quality control. In some cases you might prefer just purchase a nice 3D image and produce yourself the low res icon sizes, or have someone do it, if the icon sets aren't high res enough, or really like certain image/photo/3D for your icon. The database they have is huge.